# Update a mssql columnA until other columnB is unchanged and execute after query to update columnC

Tags: sql, sql-server

1) Is it possible to start updating `bonus` column every one hour as soon a `online` column sets to `1` ?
2) And stop updating `bonus` as soon as `online` sets to `0` ?
3) While `online` is `1`, execute a query to copy `money` to `bonus` and add `1000000` to `bonus` every hour. 
4) and replace value in `bonus` to `money` when `online` is changed to `0`.
5) `bonus` should be updated every one hour until `online` stays `1`. 

Anyone can help in this? I have the following code but its not as i expected above.

```
SELECT    db1.dbo.table.*, online AS EXPR1, money AS EXPR2
FROM      db1.dbo.table
WHERE     (online = 1) AND (reputation >= 30)
UPDATE db1.dbo.table 
SET money = (money + 1000000)
WHERE (online = 1) AND (lastupdated<DATEADD(minute, -60, GETDATE())) 
AND (reputation >= 30)
```

Comment: You could schedule a job in SQL Server, though accurate timing is not ensured. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/14/creating-a-regularly-scheduled-job.aspx).

Comment: Do you want to update a value in a row when that row's ONLINE column changes to 1?

Comment: Indeedm, this looks like a job you could run every hour on the DB server easily. Only thing is, bonuses get updated all together every hour, not one hour after "online" was set to 1. So someone who comes online just after the job runs and goes ofline after 58 minutes will not get a bonus, whereas someone who comes online just before the job runs gets a bonus after 5 minutes. This might be a problem. In that case yuo can run the job every minute and include a record timestamp in your job to check whether to update or not.

Comment: @Andrew s, i have to update a perticular column BONUS and when ONLINE is `0`, bonus should replace MONEY column

Comment: I think that you want to update each record according time in which it was set to 1 or 0. This can not be done by job, because you have to schedule it to run every second. May be you could set a trigger which updates bonuses after the change of state, but this will not show correct values in the DB. The solution in my opinion is to update from the web - when user gets online - the application updates his/her record every 1 hour.

Comment: @oerkelens yes, i have a datetime column LASTUPDATED and it will be updated when the user logs out only. is it possible to start the timing as soon as ONLINE sets to 1 in a new column?

Comment: Not sure we have enough information.  Why do you want to do this every hour?  What happens if you update the bonus column, and then the online column changes to 1?  If you want to update a column based on another column changing, then look into triggers.

Comment: @TOALL, is it possible to auto increment a datetime column as soon `online` is changed to `1`? and stop the auto increment datetime column as soon as `online` sets to `0`?

Comment: Actually, yuo could use a trigger to do the whiole thing once the user logs out: count the difference in hours between when the value changed to 1 and when it changed back to 0, multiply that by yuor 100000 and add it to your money, or bonus. No need to update every hour, bonus is handled when user goes offline.